# PHY 100MBit Link Problem (LAN8814)

Tags: ethernet, phy

We integrated a LAN switch into our design to be able to daisy chain devices and to use PTP. The switch (a LAN9668) has 2 internal CuPhy that we use. It is controlled using an SPI interface and does not run an operating system itself.

It works quiet well for 10MBit and 1GBit connections. But when setting the link to 100MBit
the link toggles between up and down and no connection is possible:

sudo ethtool -s enp5s0 autoneg on speed 100 duplex half

```
[101774.739779] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101774.739967] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101775.691848] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101777.358712] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101777.358901] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101778.322782] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101779.958651] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101779.958840] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101780.919695] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101782.687576] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101782.687764] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101783.657650] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101785.327515] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101785.327704] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101786.271584] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101787.909451] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101787.909640] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101788.848514] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101790.601430] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101790.601618] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[101791.534453] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Down
[101793.194318] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[101793.194507] e1000e 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

When polling the PHY registers the link never goes up when using 100MBit. There is an auto-negotiation complete flag that is never set.

Phy output at 1GBit:

```
1:19:17:71739 port/default/error port.c(409) port_status_poll: Enter, port 0
1:19:17:72056 cil/phy/error x.c(654) indy_poll: BSR : 0000796D, Link: 1, LinkStatus: 0
1:19:17:72103 cil/phy/error x.c(665) indy_poll: Ext Capabilty
1:19:17:72131 cil/phy/error x.c(671) indy_poll: Link is UP
1:19:17:72155 cil/phy/error x.c(674) indy_poll: Phy is able to perform Auto-Negotiation
1:19:17:72179 cil/phy/error x.c(681) indy_poll: Auto-Negotiation Completed
1:19:17:72202 cil/phy/error x.c(687) indy_poll: Extended status information in Register 15
1:19:17:72483 cil/phy/error x.c(693) indy_poll: Link code word received from partner
1:19:17:72737 cil/phy/error x.c(697) indy_poll: PMA/PCS Status Register 0806
1:19:17:74169 cil/phy/error x.c(703) indy_poll: PCS receive link status 46
1:19:17:77078 cil/phy/error x.c(737) indy_poll: AUTO or 1G
1:19:17:77590 cil/phy/error x.c(848) indy_poll: port 0 status link 1, speed 3, fdx 1
1:19:17:77630 port/default/info port.c(1733) port_poll: link up event on port_no: 0 spd:1G fdx:1
```

Phy output at 100MBit:

```
1:19:03:781575 port/default/error port.c(409) port_status_poll: Enter, port 0
1:19:03:781877 cil/phy/error x.c(654) indy_poll: BSR : 00007949, Link: 0, LinkStatus: 0
1:19:03:781924 cil/phy/error x.c(665) indy_poll: Ext Capabilty
1:19:03:781953 cil/phy/error x.c(674) indy_poll: Phy is able to perform Auto-Negotiation
1:19:03:781977 cil/phy/error x.c(684) indy_poll: Auto-Negotiation NOT Completed
1:19:03:782002 cil/phy/error x.c(687) indy_poll: Extended status information in Register 15
1:19:03:782233 cil/phy/error x.c(693) indy_poll: Link code word received from partner
1:19:03:782488 cil/phy/error x.c(697) indy_poll: PMA/PCS Status Register 0040
1:19:03:783802 cil/phy/error x.c(703) indy_poll: PCS receive link status 42
1:19:03:786360 cil/phy/error x.c(737) indy_poll: AUTO or 1G
1:19:03:786393 cil/phy/error x.c(848) indy_poll: port 0 status link 0, speed 0, fdx 1
1:19:03:805784 port/default/error port.c(409) port_status_poll: Enter, port 2
1:19:04:325716 port/default/error port.c(409) port_status_poll: Enter, port 0
1:19:04:326016 cil/phy/error x.c(654) indy_poll: BSR : 00007949, Link: 0, LinkStatus: 0
1:19:04:326065 cil/phy/error x.c(665) indy_poll: Ext Capabilty
1:19:04:326094 cil/phy/error x.c(674) indy_poll: Phy is able to perform Auto-Negotiation
1:19:04:326119 cil/phy/error x.c(684) indy_poll: Auto-Negotiation NOT Completed
1:19:04:326143 cil/phy/error x.c(687) indy_poll: Extended status information in Register 15
1:19:04:326594 cil/phy/error x.c(697) indy_poll: PMA/PCS Status Register 0040
1:19:04:327990 cil/phy/error x.c(703) indy_poll: PCS receive link status 42
1:19:04:330565 cil/phy/error x.c(737) indy_poll: AUTO or 1G
```

I can force a working connection by setting the Force Link Bit (Bit 12) of the PHYs Control Register (31). (No solution but it shows that the connection works.)

We have checked the clock 25MHz clock and it is in spec.

I read LAN8804/LAN8814 GPHY Register Definitions multiple times now, and I no longer have an idea where to look further ..

A reference design switch from microchip does not show this behavior.

A difference to reference design are the used M12 sockets (instead of RJ45). Can this effect the auto-negotiation process?

Best regards,
Gunther

Comment: After checking the schematics again, we found out that extra termination resistors were used. After removing them the problem was solved.



Bye Gunther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the schematics again, we found out that extra termination resistors were used. After removing them the problem was solved.

Bye Gunther

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please 'accept' your answer to mark this question as resolved.